# Why use create-react-app when I can just use react in the browser?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, create-react-app

I want to use react/redux. So I did "create-react-app test" after 5 minutes, I get a directory with 22,538 files and takes 131MB.

Meanwhile if I google, "jsfiddle react redux" and look at the first link I get a jsfiddle with just a few files it loads, all within the browser.

So why should I use create-react-app versus just loading a few dependencies in the browser? Is the overhead worth it? Is it mainly due to webpack?

Comment: Webpack for the most part - because it gives the commonjs module system for better code structure organizing; and as the application might become bigger you'd want to take advantage of other features - code splitting, pre-processing css via less or sass, etc.

Comment: Do you plan to deploy an app which uses React? Or are you just learning and building small examples which will not be deployed for others to use?

Answer (score 3):

I use create react app (CRA from now on) since react redux has too much boilerplate to manage things.

CRA is basically a startup-kit: that explains why has so much basic package asset in terms of import.

I can assure you that maybe you'll pay the cost to use redux on large projects (and dependencies...and packaging!!!).

Mostly depends on teams anyways, if you need to standardize how to operate on things and your team is large, Redux should be useful since this way of act avoids unexpected implementations because "there's a way" to do things.

Answer (score 2):

my personal preference is not to use `CRA`. it was meant to be a starter kit for developers who want to learn `react` without wasting time on configuration and setting up the environment.

It is a fantastic learning tool if you start from scratch because all the magic is hidden from your view, you just focus on `React` and let `cra` take care of the details. but production projects are not that simple to handle. there are a lot of requirements which may come in and your `cra` may not support it. as it was meant to be a generic tool for learning react. you can eject it but then you should really avoid ejecting it as the config is extremely complicated.

with `cra` you are missing a very important base of your project. ie the `webpack`.

The way `cra` solves this problem is by hiding all the config by default, so after starting your project you are not exposed to Babel, Webpack, dev/prod environment, or any other config.

You start learning with a tool that does everything for you, but when you are ready to know how things really work under all that, what are you supposed to do?
With `cra` you have an eject script that can uncover all the config that is hidden beneath.
If you feel so adventurous to do it, you will find yourself into a really huge and scary config, meant to do a lot of stuff and designed to not be exposed to the end user.

if you are a senior developer then you must really try to configure your own `webpack` config according to your project requirement. webpack, babel, etc are very important because they are not just for `react`. you can use them in any modern javascript project. as a senior developer, you should really know how things are working, in case you decide to remove a library and add another you should know where and how to do it. and really should not rely on a tool that makes things simple for u.

All of this is not a hard rule to follow. but my personal experience .

Comment: thanks for your answer. truthfully after using react+webpack. I'm considering using other libraries. I find the whole thing unnecessarily complicated. I'd like something like vue.js where you just add one line to html as opposed to dealing with an entire build system.

Comment: @foreyez its true the whole build system seems pointless. but we have to appreciate how these tooling and frameworks have made our life easier. like `webpack-dev-server` and `hmr` and the whole `babel` transform.

Comment: I personally think it's made my life harder. too many moving parts. I also don't think javascript, a scripting language, should be compiled. It might be good for one monolithic program, like facebook. But if you're someone that makes many, many small apps (like I do) the whole process is just inefficient.

Comment: we are only making things compatible for the older browsers. a very less percentage of users are on the older browsers. there are no other benefits for this transpilation/compilations .
I ask this questions very often, do we really care about older browsers?

Comment: if you are building small apps where you have to repeat the whole process again consider using `lerna`. you can manage local dependency with it. and you can have global confiuration which handles all the projects.. thats is something i have implemented in my current organisation.  we have like 10-12 small apps. and i use  only 1 build,test,lint config,